# list view with search functionality

Tags: android

i'm using `listview` with `BaseAdaptor`. It is working correctly but i'm also applying search functionality with it. code for it is as

```
   inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1,
                                int arg2, int arg3) {                       


                            String searchText = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                            int textLength = searchText.length();
                            searchResults.clear();

                            for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
                                String prodName = productList.get(i).get(
                                        TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                if (textLength <= prodName.length()) {
                                    if (searchText.equalsIgnoreCase(prodName
                                            .substring(0, textLength)))
                                        searchResults.add(productList.get(i));
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            lstProductList.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }

}
```

Although it is not giving me any error but also search doesn't work. nothing is happening when i write in search edittext. Where's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your BaseAdapter should implement Filterable and you should create a custom Filter class with this code in `performFiltering()`. Look at the source code for [ArrayAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter) for an example. This way you can retrieve a subset of results, but still have a copy of the original data when the EditText is cleared.

As for the logic in `onTextChanged()` it looks fine. Though you can use `startsWith()` instead of `equals()` and a `substring()`.